# Decimal representations of $2^n$ and $2^m$ are permutations of each other iff $n=m$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is my own question, with a simple solution. I wanted to share it.

Let $m,n$ be two positive integers, with the property that decimal representation of $2^n$ is a permutation of the decimal representation of $2^m$ (permutations putting $0$ as the first digit are not allowed). Then prove that $n=m$.

Comment: Should I answer it, I have a solution? or you are gonna answer yourself?

Comment: I don't think he has a question; he's presenting a problem for people to solve.

Comment: @Aaron Was your solution also this ?

Comment: Yes Jaideep :) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without loss of generality; we can assume $n \ge m$

Since these $2$ are permutations of each other, they must have same number of digits.

$$ 16 \cdot 2^m > 2^n \ge 2^m$$

This gives

> $$ m+4 > n \ge m$$

---

> If  $~\color{blue}{n=m+3}$

This gives :

$2^n-2^m=2^m(8-1) = 7 \cdot2^{m}$

Now since **the difference of permutation of a number must be divisible by $9$**, this case is rejected, since ;

$$9 \nmid 7 \cdot2^m$$

> If  $~\color{blue}{n=m+2}$

This gives :

$2^n-2^m=2^m(4-1) = 3 \cdot 2^{m}$

And ; 
$$9 \nmid 3 \cdot 2^m$$

> If $~\color{blue}{n=m+1}$

This gives :

$2^n-2^m=2^m(2-1) = 2^{m}$

And, here too ; 
$$9 \nmid 2^m$$

Therefore We are left with the only case

> $$\color{red}{{n =m}}$$

which satisfies all the above conditions.(Since $9 \mid 0$)